# Multiple machines, one mysql server on my laptop (Master Machine), one or multiple database

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, ip-address, remote-access, static-ip-address

I hope everyone reading this is doing well in all aspects of life. I have a question(s) I've been struggling with and I'm looking for the help of the community.

I have recently ventured into the world of coding. I wish my high school did a better job of helping us understand the opportunities that are in this field. Thats here nor there.

**Please note that I am as new to this field as new can be. If you can take my problems as your own and try to answer them as you would your own problems i'd greatly appreciate it.**

I wanted to know if and how its possible to do the following.

I have created a software that I want to use on multiple machines. Say for this example 90 total different machines. Those machines (Laptops, desktops, etc.) are miles apart for now. And in the future if all goes well few hundred or even thousands of miles apart (100,000+ machines). I want to know **how can I connect all those different machines to a running MySQL database (server) located in my laptop?** Once connected, **do I have to keep my laptop on at all times** or would it be possible to use my laptop as I do now and when I shut it, turn it off, or restart it, will those other machines connected be disconnect?

When connecting to a remote machine to MySQL database on my machine **do I or does the other machine need internet?** or both or none?

In doing my research I have read cPanel and Google Cloud are some of the few I could use. At this moment I'm not in a financial position to able to buy any cloud services, however down the line they are in my medium term goals. **What are other alternatives?** Could I use for example my **Gmail account remaining balance? OneDrive etc..?**  if so how? or are there any free cloud services i could use to assist me with that for the short term foreseeable future to achieve my goals?

Would it be possible to be in control of the software and say if a client decided to tamper with the code or attempt to change it or clone in anyway. Could I use the master machine to change the password or deactivate that user for breaking our contractual agreement?

Few times I have attempted to use puTTY to connect to the IP address provided by my internet provider. However i was denied access. **Once I created a static IP address my internet no longer worked.** **How can I maneuver around that?** Is it possible to **create a static address and still be able to access the internet?** Do I need to talk to my internet provider to allow me any special permissions?

What are the difference between the following: **Link-local IPv6 Address, IPv4 Address, Subnet mask, Default Gateway**

*Any theory, idea, or solution, would you mind posting a video or any reading material be it a book or an article*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Everything is possible in the world of Computer. So, learn more, do more research.

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow - each question should contain at most ONE question to a problem which has an objective answer. Read our help centre for more information. [That being said, I might be able to answer a few of your questions...](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/LCx3t02u)